# Conditional expectation, conditional on sum of weighted average of two iid RVs

Tags: bayesian, sum, conditional

I have an *arbitrary* distribution $F$, and two variables $z, x \sim F$.

I only observe the weighted average $y = \alpha z + (1 - \alpha) x$. Conditional on $y$, what is the expected value of $z$?

I know I can use Baye's rule for this, but we only wish to know $\mathbb{E}(z \mid y)$, so calculating the full distribution of $f(z \mid y)$ seems excessive, and potentially intractable. Plus if I can write something in terms of the moments of $F$, then that's a nicer solution.

I have made progress in (I think) a clever direction.

Given that $y = \alpha z + (1 - \alpha) x$, we can apply the conditional expectation operator and know

$\alpha\mathbb{E}(z \mid y) = y - (1 - \alpha)\mathbb{E}(x \mid y)$

Assume that the conditional expectation is of the form $\mathbb{E}(z \mid y) = f(y, \alpha)$. Then we also know that $\mathbb{E}(x \mid y) = f(y, 1 - \alpha)$. This gives us the relationship

$$
\alpha f(y, \alpha) = y - (1 - \alpha) f(y, 1 - \alpha)
$$

We also know that

$$
f(y, 0) = \mathbb{E}(z)
$$

That is, when $\alpha = 0$, knowing $y$ tells us nothing about $z$. Similarly, we also know $f(y, 1) = y$.

Given the three conditions

$$
\alpha f(y, \alpha) = y - (1 - \alpha) f(y, 1 - \alpha) \\
f(y, 0) = \mathbb{E}(z) \\
f(y, 1) = y
$$

Can we figure out all of $f$?

Comment: Either you assume that $X$ and $Z$ are independent, in which case the equation$$\alpha\mathbb{E}(Z \mid Y=y) = y - (1 - \alpha)\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y=y)$$will provide the answer, or you do not, in which case the answer will (only) depend on $\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y=y)$

Answer (score 0):

In the normal case, where $z \sim N(0, 1)$, and $z \sim N(0, 1)$ and are independent, we have

$$
\mathbb{E}(z \mid y) = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2 + (1 - \alpha)^2}y
$$

Proof:

It's easy to show that when we have random variables $a \sim N(0, 1), b \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ that

$$
\mathbb{E}(a \mid y) = \frac{1}{1+\sigma^2}y
$$

In this context, we can divide by $\alpha$ and get

$$
\frac{y}{\alpha} = z + \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}z
$$

This gives

$$
\mathbb{E}(z \mid y) = \left(\frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\right)^2} \right)\frac{y}{\alpha} 
$$

Which simplifies nicely to the original expression.

The question is then, does this hold for any other distributions? Maybe its easy to show that

$$
f(y, \alpha) = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2 + (1 - \alpha)^2}y
$$

is the *only* function satisfying the properties outlined in the main question.

EDIT: I added some Julia code which indicates that this is *not* the only function satisfying these properties.

I simulate data with a normal distribution and a Frechet distribution. Then I do an ad-hoc kernel estimation wheere I just take the mean of $z$ within small groups of $y$.

Clearly the function $f$ for Normal is different than the function $f$ for Frechet. [image]

```
julia> using DataFrames, Distributions, Chain, CategoricalArrays;

julia> function make_data(N, D, α)
       mD = mean(D)
       t = map(1:N) do _
           z = rand(D) - mD
           x = rand(D) - mD
           y = α * z + (1 - α) * x
           (;z, x, y)
       end |> DataFrame
       end;

julia> function plot_y_z!(df, label)
           df.c = cut(df.y, 1000)
           df_c = combine(groupby(df, :c), [:y, :z] .=> mean)
           plot!(df_c.y_mean, df_c.z_mean; label = label)
       end;

julia> p = plot();

julia> @chain begin 
           make_data(1_000_000, Normal(0, 1), .3)
           plot_y_z!("Normal")
       end;

julia> @chain begin 
           make_data(1_000_000, Frechet(5), .3)
           plot_y_z!("Frechet")
       end;

julia> gui()
```